# React native select multiple items with sliding our fingers

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist, panresponder

When the Pan is Respod in `Flatlist` I want to select this item like the iOS file app. I really want to use this on my app to select multiple component list items.

I have tried using this https://github.com/sushantdsuwal/DragAndSelectMultipleItems example but facing an issue with `FlatList` and `ScrollView`.

Comment: Please explain what issue your are having, otherwise we can't help you. You could also try using `react-native-gesture-handler`. These types of gestures can be easily handled using it.